# how do nodejs tasks actually run?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to figure out exactly how nodejs tasks are run.  I understand that there is a main loop that takes requests and then queues them up and moves on.  What exactly then executes those queued up events/tasks?

Update:

Can somebody actually please explain it?  I appreciate people wanting me to script it and figure it out myself, but sometimes it's better to just have it explained rather than creating barriers to learning simple concepts.

Answer (score -1):

you can follow https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector

use can use node-inspector to select a script and set some breakpoints,help you to understand event loop,